# Adding image to combobox values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

*MainWindow has following xaml for combobox*

**MainWindowViewModel.xaml**

```
<ComboBox Name="CountryComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Countries, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCountry, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ComboBox>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
private string _SelectedCountry;
public string SelectedCountry
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedCountry;
    }
    set
    {
        _SelectedCountry = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCountry");
    }
}

public List<string> Countries {get; set;}
public MainViewModel()
{ 
    Countries = new List<string>();
    var a = "Avganistan";
    var b = "Azerbeijan";
    Countries.Add(a);
    Countries.Add(b);      
}
```

How can I add images to this countries combobox values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Declare a proper `Country` class that implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and that has `string Name` and `ImageSource` properties and a constructor that takes these input parameters.

b) Update the definition of your `Countries` property to be of type `ObservableCollection<Country>`.

c) Add items of this new class into your new `Countries` collection:

```
Countries.Add(new Country("Some Country", 
    "pack://application:,,,/AppName;component/Images/Some Country Image.png"));
Countries.Add(new Country("Other Country", 
    "pack://application:,,,/AppName;component/Images/Other Country Image.png"));
```

d) Define a `DataTemplate` for your `Country` class (either in the XAML `Resources` where the `ComboBox` will be or in `App.xaml`):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:Country}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="None" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

e) Finally, just data bind your collection property to the `ItemsSource` property of a collection control:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" />
```

Comment: It is not necessary to replace `List` with `ObservableCollection` cause it is initialized in constructor of `ViewModel`

Comment: It is not necessary to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface either, but it's good practice.